# How can I select only the first general sibling that is not a script tag?

Tags: html, css

I have structure/style similar to snippet below.  I'm trying to target the first element that is not a script tag, without knowing what type of element it is.  (I inherited an old codebase and parts will not be updated by me.)

As you can see, I tried `header ~ :not(script):first-of-type` but that selects all general siblings that are not a script tag.

I also tried `header ~ :not(script):first-child`, but that doesn't select anything.  Any ideas?

```css
header ~ :not(script):first-of-type{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>This is the header</header>
  <script>// This script tag may or may NOT be present</script>
  <section>These are the section tags, <strong>that may also be DIV tags</strong> (or some other wrapper) in some cases</section>
  <footer>This is the footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it one line of CSS (that I'm aware of), but try using the adjacent selector :)

```css
header + *:not(script) { color: red; }
header + script + * { color: red; }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>This is the header</header>
  <script>// This script tag may or may NOT be present</script>
  <section>These are the section tags, <strong>that may also be DIV tags</strong> (or some other wrapper) in some cases</section>
  <footer>This is the footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tyblitz for pointing me in the right direction.  Your answer doesn't work in the case of more than one script tag (I could have made this case more obvious in the question.) But the following rules seem to work:

```
header + :not(script),
header ~ script + :not(script) { color: red; }
```

**Update** - that ^ didn't work because it selects script tags anywhere after header.  Unfortunately I had to go with this (and hope at max 2 script tags may follow header):

```
header + :not(script),
header + script + :not(script),
header + script + script + :not(script) { color: red; }
```

I don't think there's a better way, but any thoughts for improving this ugliness are much obliged.

```css
header + :not(script),
header + script + :not(script),
header + script + script + :not(script) { color: red; }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>This is the header</header>
  <script>//Script tags may or may not be present</script>
  <script>//and there may be more than one</script>
  <section>These are the section tags, <strong>that may also be DIV tags</strong> (or some other wrapper) in some cases</section>
  <script>//Script tags may follow original target</script>
  <div>This is a div</div>
  <footer>This is the footer</footer>
</body>
```